# Can I return html from a view to a controller?

Tags: asp.net-core, view-components

I have a view component for displaying lists of products. The component is called with model and data and is more or less just layouting the products. This is reused from multiple views.

I would like to add the option to "dynamic" include a call to the viewcomponent from a controller.
One example would be to store a merge code in the database, something like |:ShowProductsOnSale:|
When this string is found, I would like to make a call to the ViewComponent, get the html back to the controller and replace |:ShowProductsOnSale:| with the html.
Is it possible at all? Or might there be a better solution that I havn't thought of?

```
if (content.IndexOf("|:ShowProductsOnSale:|") > 0)
{
  // Somehow get content of ViewComponent
  var html = _some_content;
  content = content.Replace("|:ShowProductsOnSale:|", html);
}
```

** EDIT **
The "dynamic" load that I need, is for users to be able to add the list of products on sale, where ever they want.

I cannot call the viewcomponent directly from the controller, because i don't know where to use it. A user might be creating a page with some content (posting the content including html to a database)
The content might include something like:

```
Here is a list of our product currently on sale<br>|:ShowProductsOnSale:|<br>
Click on a product above to buy it.
```

I need some way to replace the |:ShowProductsOnSale:| with the content created by the viewcompnent.
I also need to make the replace in the controller, because i need to send data to the viewcomponent

Comment: I don't understand the difference between |:ShowProductsOnSale:| and directly call use viewcomponent  inside the view. In my opinion, they are the same, one is using the method to do it, another you should check the conetent and call the viewcomponent  again.  If you have some speicific logic, we could use the code to call it, otherwise, no need do it.

Comment: You can use your logic on your component code. Is there any product to show them? If there is, so show them. If there is not, so don't show anything or show the message: `nothing for sale`. You don't need to check the Component separately.